# VS2015 not linking user32.lib

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015

I just inherited maintenance on a 10-year-old project, which includes moving it from VS2005 to VS2015.  I'm most of the way there, but when I link I get this error:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxA@16

A quick search found that that this requires user32.lib.  When I go to properties->linker->Additional Dependencies, I see that library liste under Inherited Values, but it still doesn't link.  When I explicitly add the hardcoded path and filename (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86\user32.lib) as another dependency, then it does successfully link... which is okay, I guess, but if nothing else it's ugly that I'm relying on that particular install location (you know software developers are going to decide to stick things in odd places)...  Anybody have any guesses as to why visual studio isn't finding the library in the first place, and how to fix it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Take the dependency on the lib file at the project level, and then [add your paths to your properties page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/vcpp-directories-property-page?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Projects.VCDirectories)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2015).

Answer (score 1):

The `Windows Kits\8.1` tells you that you have the Windows 8.1 SDK installed. There's a Windows 10 SDK by now, but that probably doesn't really matter to you - user32.lib has been around since forever.

The problem here seems to be that while you have the 8.1 SDK installed, Visual Studio isn't aware of it. IIRC, it's in the VS2015 installer, so you can rerun that and re-select the SDK there. (Or pick another SDK - you're likely going to be restricting the SDK to Win7 anyway)